# Getting empty or whitespaces for some of the SVG images when using svgcrop.com

Tags: svg, crop, removing-whitespace

Tried to crop the image https://freesvg.org/sophia-and-the-beast using https://svgcrop.com/, getting empty or whitespaces as highlighted in the attachment, though it is working fine for several other images.

[image with whitespace after crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZKCJ.png)

@user3521314, Need your help on this to get rid of the whitespaces.

To remove the whitespaces around SVG images using svgcrop.com

Comment: I've downloaded the image and there are no empty spaces around it. Why do you need to crop it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have uploaded the image "sophia-and-the-beast" in svgcrop.com,  if you notice the tile image, there are whitespaces around the image. Want to get the image fixed fully in the tile view.

Comment: please try this viewBox="20 40 435 380"  abd delete the height of the svg element. Let me know if this is what you need

Comment: Yes, this gives the proper image. Please let me know how to get this viewbox values from the given svg. Also, I need to apply the same logic for other svg images as well.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no specific method so that you can use in javascript. All I've done was drawing a rect at the end of the code and changing the x y width and height till all the white spaces were left out of the rect.   <rect stroke="white" stroke-width="2" fill="none" x="20" y="40" width="435" height="380"/> Then I've used the x y width and height values  for the new viewBox.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am looking for a way to find out programmatically to eliminate the whitespaces.